# How to update column based on filter of another column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to basically update a subset of rows in a table using a filter but currently my query is updating all values instead of the intended subset.  I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

Here's what the current (non working) `update` looks like.

```
UPDATE account_type
SET type_id = 3
FROM my_filter;
```

I have been able to successfully select the data I want, I just can't figure out how to get the update to work.  I am able to access the fields correctly with the following `select` statement.

```
SELECT account_type FROM my_filter;
```

But when I attempt to update, it updates every field.  Here's what the (working) `join` I have looks like, wrapped in a CTE.

```
WITH my_filter AS
(
  SELECT account_type.type_id, username
  FROM account_type
  INNER JOIN user ON user.account_id = account_type.account_id
  WHERE username LIKE 'filter%'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `join` condition.  I would guess:

```
UPDATE account_type
    SET type_id = 3
    FROM my_filter
    WHERE account_type.type_id = my_filter.type_id;
```

Alternative, you can write this as:

```
UPDATE account_type
    SET type_id = 3
    FROM user
    WHERE user.account_id = account_type.account_id AND
          user.username LIKE 'filter%';
```

Comment: The first join in your answer isn't working quite right (I may be doing something wrong), but the second example you posted works.